# Quartz error when upgrading spring version

Tags: spring, datasource, quartz

I upgraded the spring version from 4.3.12 to 5.3.20, but when I ran the server locally, I got the following error. FYI, I didn't use the spring boot, but I checked with debugging, and it seems to be getting data from the .xml setup file well, so why is that?

Is Spring 5.3.20 different from 4.3.12 when it comes to making db connections or data sources?

spring: 5.3.20
quartz: 2.3.2

```
[2023-09-06 16:24:46,150] [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] WARN  o.q.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.shutdown:748 - Database connection shutdown unsuccessful.
java.sql.SQLException: There is no DataSource named 'null'
```

I upgraded the spring version because I wanted to use the 5 version of junit.